# How do I avoid "filling in" a stroke in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fill, pen-tool

So I was trying to create a leaf using the pen tool. Each of the 8 stems were drawn as separate strokes using the pen tool. My fill is set to none but still a black fill shows up. **a)** How do I avoid this? Also, why is this happening? 
Also, another issue I had was when I tried drawing the paths (stems of the leaf), they would join and automatically fill in with a black fill. So I had to draw them separately and move around the ends of the stem to join using the direct selection tool.
**b)** Is there a better way to join separate strokes(created by the pen tool) without them joining automatically?

Tried searching for something related to this but all I found was how to fill strokes whereas I'm trying to **avoid** filling a stroke here.

[image: Img]

Answer (score 1):

Random educated guess.......

The filled dot to the right of the layer in the **Layers Panel** would suggest that the **layer** has an appearance applied to it. Check the **Appearance Panel** to see if the Layer itself has any appearance attributes. Most likely, a fill. So, anything on that layer subsequently gets the same fill.

[image]